# Implement created_on and updated_on logic on client side

Tags: elasticsearch, design-patterns, logic

From elasticsearch > 2, there is no `_timestamp` field. we have to explicitly populate time fields like `created_on` and `updated_on`

One way i know to populate these fields is check item to be populated is already existing in Database using `uid` (assume `uid` generated on client side using some item properties). If item exists in Database, update all fields except `created_on`. If item does not exist, create entry in database  with item and `created_on` equal to current time.

My questions are:
 * Isn't checking every time i create/update redundant ??
 * Is there any better way to implement `created_on` and `updated_on` logic on client side without redundant (without querying elasticsearch) ??

Answer (score 0):

Using a "middleware" for this is a good way to avoid having this kind of logic in the client, once you change the design, you would need to perform changes on every client implementation, so I think is a good use case for ingesting pipelines and there is an example in the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-ingest-metadata).

> Accessing Ingest Metadata Fields:
>   Beyond metadata fields and source fields, ingest also adds ingest metadata to the documents that it processes. These metadata properties are accessible under the _ingest key. Currently ingest adds the ingest timestamp under the _ingest.timestamp key of the ingest metadata. The ingest timestamp is the time when Elasticsearch received the index or bulk request to pre-process the document.

If you need more intelligent middleware, mind the [Script Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html#script-processor) which allows inline and stored scripts to be executed within ingest pipelines.